# Openstack on Xenial Networking

Tags: networking, openstack

What would it mean when Openstack created VMs can ping other machines on the external network--both VMs and physical machines-- but NOT the physical router(default gateway)?
Nor can the physical router ping the floating IPs of the VMs?
Could it be the wireless router's problem?
I chose FLAT when creating the external Openstack network because in vxlan it seems that one has to enter the qrouter namespace(ip netns) to have access to the VMs.
All configuration seems totally absolutely correct.
But still............
Unable to ping the default gateway and thus access the internet..
Please bear with my ignorance.
I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work.It WAS the wifi adapter.When i used an ethernet cable to connect my machine to the router the VMs were able to ping the router and connect to the internet.Therefore never use OVS networking over wifi.